# python iterating through lists

Tags: python, list, loops

Consider the lists below

```
filters= [u,    i,  g,    r,    z]
result = [None, 34, None, None, 45]
```

the items in the `result` are computed for each filter in `filters`. It happens that filters, `u, g, z` did not return any results. So i would to re-compute the values of `result[0], result[2], result[4],` using the filters that returned values.

My problem is iterating through both lists and using the closet filter to compute a value missing in result.
e.g `result[0]` should be computed using `'i'` (`i` is closest to `u`) `result[2]` we also use `'i'` not `'z'` and `result[3]` we use `'z'`. How to generalize this?? (filters are fixed, but items in values keep changing.) What i would like to get is a tuple with two filters, (filter_missing_a_value_in_results, filter_to_used_to_computer_the_missing_value)

Comment: What would happen with `result[2]` if `result[3]` were populated?

Comment: Any closest filter can be used the one before or after

Comment: You can't have "before or after". You need to define your behavior.

Comment: After is the best option- but if  last value is not known, then a before can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not particularly efficient solution:

```
def filters_by_distance(i):
    '''Generate filters by distance from i'''
    sorted_indices = sorted(range(len(filters)), key=lambda j: abs(j-i))
    return (filters[j] for j in sorted_indices)
```